# Bottom bracket for 1991 raleigh classic man

Tags: bottom-bracket, raleigh, threaded-bottom-bracket

Got a Raleigh classic man from a scrap shop. Decided to give it a life. The frame is in good condition and managed to get bearing hubs for front and rear wheels. I was wondering what would size and dimension would be a good fit bottom bracket? I want something other than the default ball and cone bottom bracket? Any help, suggestion is much appreciated.

**Edit**:

Shell width: 70mm

Comment: first of all, measure the shell width of the bottom bracket. With Raleigh, it could be a standard that everyone is familiar with, or it could be their own special size that doesn't give you many options. Please check and let us know.

Comment: Updated the shell width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the shell width as 70mm.

This is a problem on the Raleigh bikes, which as far as I know, never use an Italian threading (which is also a 70mm width).

A normal British bottom bracket shell is 68mm.

The 70mm indicates that the bottom bracket uses Raleigh's own thread pitch for which replacements are no longer available. It is possible, though not a fantastic option, to re cut the threads with standard BSC/British thread pitch though this weakens the thread somewhat, and will give a small centreline error with your new cranks on a square taper BB as the shell is 2mm wider than it should be. You can't install most threadless bottom brackets as the thread engagement is usually not enough over the 70mm shell. You could also see about having the shell reamed out and cut with Italian threads (for which the 70mm width would be correct).

No easy answers, sorry.

This page provides more detail so you can compare what you've got in front of you and see if I'm right.

https://sheldonbrown.com/raleigh26.html

> Right through the 1990s, the bikes built at the mighty Nottingham Factory were made to Raleigh proprietary dimensions. Since Raleigh made virtually every part of these bikes, there was no compelling need to match standards used by other manufacturers

If you re-measure and find the shell is actually 68mm, that changes the situation!

Comment: were there 70mm raleigh BBs made as late as the 90s? i thought that was a 70s and earlier thing.

Comment: @NathanKnutson Probably not, but some aspect is "wrong" and that could be the date. I believe bikes were still manufactured in Nottingham that late so it isn't totally impossible even if unlikely.

Comment: @NathanKnutson see edit with quote from link. Thanks.

Comment: Mm.. The chance of re-measurement, yielding 68mm is slim and cannot be ruled out, with a vernier caliper. Let me do that and update.